# Shopify - Adding Cookies Within Shopify After Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, shopify, setcookie

Very new to the whole cookie within shopify situation, but can someone tell me how to get a cookie inserted after a customer has paid for a product.

The premise being, installed an app called OptinMonster and they have a call cookie function so theory being , once a customer has paid for an item a notification pops up.

If someone could help that would be great!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can set a cookie in your checkout settings in Shopify. I found this doc that may help: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/add-conversion-tracking-to-thank-you-page

And this: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/save-cookie-on-thankyou-page-394380

Please feel free to reach out directly to OptinMonster support if you need more help. Just log in to your OptinMonster account & click "Help" at the top to submit a ticket. We're here for you! :)

Comment: Hi Keri, So conversion tracking is known as a cookie for shopify?